# Проблема с форматированным выводом

Tags: python

Вычисляю факториал. При выводе результатов возникает ошибка, которую у меня не получается исправить. Ошибка в 11 строке: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'. Не знаю как исправить её.

Ещё нужно сделать так, чтобы в консоли было видно этапы вычисления факториала.
Например:
Ввожу 5!
5*4=20*3=60*2=120

```
def factorial(number): # объявил функцию "факториал" с аргументом "номер итерации"
    if number == 0: # если факториал = 0, выхожу из цикла; иначе - иду дальше
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number-1)

print('Введите число, факториал которого нужно вычислить: ')
n = input()
print()

print('{n}! = ' + factorial(eval(n)).format(n = n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Вашей задачи удобнее промежуточный (невычесленный) результат хранить в виде строки - `str_num` в данном коде. Например, для числа 4 `str_num` при увеличении глубины рекурсии сначала принимает значение, `4`, потом `4*3`, `4*3*2`, и наконец `4*3*2*1`. При этом, в виде челого числа (`int_num`) то, во что превратилось в ходе рекурсии изначальное число, можно получить разделив `str_num` по разделителю `*` и взяв последний (-1-ый) элемент полученного списка. Ну и финальный результат - это `eval` указанного `str_num`

```
def fact(str_num):
    int_num = int(str_num.split('*')[-1])

    # здесь выводится промежуточный вариант
    if int_num == int(n):
        print('{}! = '.format(n), end='')
    if int_num > 1:
        print('{0} * {1}!'.format(eval(str_num), int_num-1), end=' = ')
    else:
        print('{0} * {1} = {2}'.format(eval(str_num), int_num, eval(str_num)*int_num), end='')

    if int_num > 1:
        str_num += '*{}'.format(int_num-1)
        return fact(str_num)
    else:
        return str_num

n = input('enter number: ')

result_str = fact(n)

print()

print('{}! ='.format(n), result_str, '=', eval(result_str))
```

---

Если ввести `5`, вывод будет:

```
5! = 5 * 4! = 20 * 3! = 60 * 2! = 120 * 1! = 120 * 1 = 120
5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
```

---

**P.S.**

`number` -- это не номер итерации, а результат уменьшения исходного числа с увеличением глубины рекурсии

`if number == 0: return 1` -- это верно, но можно возвращать единицу получив 1, а не ноль, т.к. 1! = 1 тоже

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(number): # объявил функцию "факториал" с аргументом "номер итерации"
    if number == 0: # если факториал = 0, выхожу из цикла; иначе - иду дальше
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number-1)

print('Введите число, факториал которого нужно вычислить: ')
n = input()
print()

print(('{n}! = ' + str(factorial(eval(n)))).format(n = n))
```

Ошибка была в том, что вы пытались использовать функцию format для числа, когда ее можно применять только к строке.

Answer (score 0):

тут все просто

```py
def factorial(number): # объявил функцию "факториал" с аргументом "номер итерации"
    if number == 0: # если факториал = 0, выхожу из цикла; иначе - иду дальше
        return 1
    else:
        return number * factorial(number-1)

print('Введите число, факториал которого нужно вычислить: ')
n = input()
print()

print('n! = {}'.format(str(factorial(eval(n)))))
```

Comment: А как показать этапы вычисления факториала. Например: Ввожу 5! 5*4=20*3=60*2=120 Это же реально?

Comment: @РоманРатушный да, вполне, только правильно это будет так - 5! = 5 * 4! = 5 * 4 * 3!...